# SQL Client Connection namespace or class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone here know reference links or how to create an Object Oriented Connection on ASP.NET C# which handle OPEN Connection, Close Connection, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT and populating. It much better if I have this on a single class or namespace which I can call every time I'm dealing on database transaction for code re-usability and efficiency. I'm newbie on C# but I know the importance of organizing the database transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the choice will depend on the requirements of the system you want to build. There are many options for you to choose from:

1. [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) => Fantastic performance, build on top of ADO.NET, Stackoverflow themselves using it.
2. Using a ORM such as:

   - [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) => Good for quick prototype, non-complex system.
   - [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/) => Good for complex system but not too complex, such as CMS for example. It has very good transaction & session implementation.
3. Creating your own implementation of Data Access and have full control of every interaction with your database.

Answer (score 2):

[Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

EF is simple to implement you create a class that inherits from DbContext.

This class defines a property with a DbSet where T is the type you are backing to a data base.

Then you setup a connection string. And specify what to do when initializing the DB.

You treat your DbSet as a list you can add to it. Search it. Remove from it. Alter things inside it. The only difference is when you're done you have to call

```
db.myDataSet.SaveChanges();
```

if you want direct access to calling sql commands read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx)

```
var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: just want to try hard coded structure. just want to familiar the coding. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you're a newbie, you should start with Enterprise Library.And gradually move on to ORMs like EntityFramework or others.

This is where you should start:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440726(v=pandp.60).aspx